# Send File location from javascript to Asp.net Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am using a file input to let the user upload a file which is to be attached later on at the controller level to an email. I am extending an application and the email class that already exists takes the path of the file as a string. Is there a way to pass the file from javascript (i know that browsers cant get full path for security reasons) and once i have the file on the aspnet web api 2 controller to get the filepath there?
I am not sure if code is really needed here so i will omit that for now unless requested for a specific reason.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the form gets submitted you have to save file on server in temp location and use it in another controller or view later and delete it, but you cannot hold to path.

Comment: Why is it so important that you know the client location of the file?

Comment: Even if you know the client location the server will probably won't have access to it

Comment: It is because the Email class i was provided with, to get attach the file to the email requires a string which represents its location can you think of a way to do it as it is or it seems that the email calss requires modification to accept a file?